# WPF: Binding to MainWindow Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, visibility

I am having an issue with binding to a parent MainWindow property, MainContentVisibility.  I have the following code:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="CallTracker.WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MyProgram.WPF.Views"
        DataContext="{Binding MainPageViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

        <StackPanel>
            <v:CompanyInfoUserControl Width="800" Visibility="{Binding MainContentVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
            <v:MainContentUserControl Width="800" Visibility="{Binding Path=MainContentVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
        </StackPanel>   
</Window>
```

Currently my two user controls are nothing more than a stack panel with a text block until I figure out this Visibility issue.

I can use Snoop to check my MainPageViewModel and I can see that the property MainContentVisibilty is set to "Collapsed" but the CompanyInfoUserControl shows an issue with its Visibility binding:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'MainContentVisibility' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow'
>   (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=MainContentVisibility;
>   DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is
>   'CompanyInfoUserControl' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility'
>   (type 'Visibility')

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

I tried paul's suggestion and now I get this as the binding error from Snoops:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'MainContentVisibility' property not found on 'object'
>   ''MainPageViewModel' (HashCode=63642613)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=MainContentVisibility;
>   DataItem='MainPageViewModel' (HashCode=63642613); target element is
>   'CompanyInfoUserControl' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility'
>   (type 'Visibility')

**SOLUTION**

I wasn't actually binding to my data model but rather the XAML object (in this case MainWindow.xaml)  In order to bind to the data I had to add the reference 'DataContext' as follows:

```
<v:CompanyInfoUserControl Visibility="{Binding DataContext.MainContentVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

Comment: Can you click on the accepted tick for one of the answers please (as opposed to putting SOLVED in the title of the question)

Answer (score 3):

I take it that `MainContentVisibility` is not on the ViewModel?

If you want to access it on the main window's property away from the viewmodel, then provide a name for the window such as `x:Name="MyMainWindow"` and the access it in the binding

```
Visibility="{Binding MainContentVisibility, ElementName=MyMainWindow}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have the `DataContext` of the `Window` set to the `MainPageViewModel`.  Child elements will inherit this `DataContext` so there is no need for your relative pathing.  All you need is:

```
<v:CompanyInfoUserControl Width="800" Visibility="{Binding Path=MainContentVisibility}" />
```

Your current code is looking for a property called `MainContentVisibility` on the `Window` control itself, not the view model.

Comment: See my edit to the OP (so I could use the blcok quote to make the comment easier to read).

Comment: Check your Locator.  You're sure the `MainPageViewModel` property is actually returning a `MainPageViewModel`?  Because this says the Locator is giving you a `CompanyInfoViewModel`.

Comment: I must have cut and paste incorrectly.  I re-ran the Snoops and have updated my OP Edit.  It is trying to bind to MainPageViewModel but even though I can clearly see the MainContentVisibility property in MainPageViewModel using Snoops, it still won't bind to it.

Comment: I'd like to see the MainPageViewModel and Locator code.